# Android Studio Proguard config file

Tags: android

I need to add `-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }` in Proguard config file but I don't know where is Proguard config file located in Android Studio

Comment: It is called `proguard-rules.pro` and located at the root folder when you pick Android view for your project in Android Studio

Answer (score 17):

Go to `Gradle Scripts` and then look for a file called `proguard-rules.pro` and there you can edit it.

[image]

If you are using the `Project view` you can find it here

[image]

From docs

> The proguard-rules.pro file is where you can add custom ProGuard rules. By default, this file is located at the root of the module (next to the build.gradle file).

For more information take a look at [Shrink your code and resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)